# Reuse Jest module mocks across tests

Tags: jestjs, mocking, next.js, es6-modules

I want to mock a module for a test. Everything works, but I have to copy/paste the same code into every test file. How can I make this more maintainable?

*(This is using Babel and TypeScript in a Next.js project.)*

The production code looks like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

// Then call the hook in a React component:
  const router = useRouter();
```

The test code:

```
// I need to access these mocks in the tests
const mockRouterPush = jest.fn();
const mockRouterBack = jest.fn();

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: mockRouterPush,
    query: { segment: 'seg1' },
    back: mockRouterBack,
  }),
}));
```

This works fine. The module and its hook are mocked for the test file, and I can refer to the mocks in the tests. The issue is that it's difficult to maintain across multiple test files.

Calls to [jest.mock()](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter) are hoisted to the top of the file, and can only refer to variables that start with the word 'mock'.

With other mocks I've used `require` within the module factory instead of `import`; this works and reduces boilerplate, but (a) makes it more difficult for the tests to refer to the mocks and (b) my IDE (VSCode) won't auto-update require paths like it does with imports when I move files. For example:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => {
  // Sometimes the path is '../../../testhelpers' etc.
  const { mockUseTranslation } = require('./testhelpers');

  return {
    useTranslation: mockUseTranslation,
  };
});
```

I've tried `doMock` and `createMockFromModule` without success.

How do other folks deal with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe using the `__mocks__` directory can help you.

from the docs:

> Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a **__mocks__**/ subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. For example, to mock a module called user in the models directory, create a file called user.js and put it in the models/**__mocks__** directory.

You can also mock modules from the `node_modules` directory.

[Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)

Comment: Thank you! A coworker mentioned that as well and I just tried it successfully.
Nesting works: __mocks__/next/router.js
Then just `jest.mock('next/router')`
To access the mocks I can do `import { useRouter } from 'next/router'` in the tests, then `const { push: mockRouterPush } = useRouter()` (disabling rules-of-hooks).

Comment: editing the answer is impossible, but wanted to point out. the folder name should be `__mocks__`, the **s** is important.